# libxercesc can not catch exception only on Solaris

Tags: exception, solaris, xerces-c

ffffffff7e54c2f0 __lwp_sigqueue (6, 6, 5, 0, 6, 5) + 8

ffffffff7e4cab0c abort (ffffffff79415998, 0, 6, ffffffff7bf002d8, 1bb5b4, c00) + c4

ffffffff7930ab8c _*1cH__CimplRdefault_terminate6F_v* (ffffffff79415998,

ffffffff7e68cfc0, 28a0, ffffffff7930ab88, 0, ffffffff79415998) + 4

ffffffff7930a958 _*1cH__CimplMex_terminate6F_v* (ffffffff79411940, 0,

ffffffff79411940, 1, ffffffff794107b8, 0) + 28

ffffffff7930b7dc _ex_throw_body (ffffffff79411940, 0, ffffffff7c807f50,
ffffffffffffffff, 0, fffc00) + c4

ffffffff7930b6e8 _*1cG__CrunIex_throw6Fpvpkn0AQstatic_type_info_pF1_v_v* (ffffffff79411940, 1, fffffff82c00b020, ffffffff79411940,
ffffffff794107b8, b0) + 78

fffffff82c0131dc **1cLxercesc_3_1ODOMAttrMapImplPremoveNamedItem6MpkH_pn0AHDOMNode** (182fd8000, 182fa2640, 5, 10a6376e9, 182f8b320, 80808080) + 334
...

xercesc-3.1.0 library compile

`--tag=CXX   --mode=link CC  -g -mt -library=stlport4 -m64 -xcode=pic32 -D_REENTRANT  -release 3.1 -64 -o libxerces-c.la -rpath ~~blahblah.lo ...`

`CC -xar -o .libs/libxerces-c.a   xercesc/util/Base64.o xercesc/util/BinFileInputStream.o ~~blahblah`

uname -a

`SunOS solaris-2016 5.11 11.3 sun4v sparc sun4v`

version /usr/lib/libCrun.so.1

`/usr/lib/libCrun.so.1: Sun SUNWlibC SunOS 5.11 SunOS_sparc s11u3_24 2015/06/02`

$ CC -V

`CC: Sun C++ 5.13 SunOS_sparc 2014/10/20`

$ cc -V

`cc: Sun C 5.13 SunOS_sparc 2014/10/20`

Even when building the xercesc library as both a static library and a dynamic library, the same issue persists.

Comment: First, none of the posted names can be demangled by either `dem` from the Oracle compiler suite nor `c++filt`.  Second, you need to post both the link commands for the executable(s) using your library, and the output from `ldd -r -s ...` for those executable(s).  You're likely not linking the executable(s) properly, or worse, the executable(s) also have a dependency on the GNU `libstdc++.so` C++ runtime library.  Mixing multiple C++ runtime libraries in one executable is not going to work.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. When running ldd on the executable, I found that libstdc++.so.6 was present. I removed the libraries that depend on libstdc++.so.6. However, I am still experiencing the issue with _1cH__CimplRdefault_terminate6F_v. I don't suspect any other suspicious libraries. I will try building libxerces-c and libxqilla as static libraries.

Comment: ...
libm.so.2 => /lib/64/libm.so.2
librt.so.1 => /lib/64/librt.so.1
...
libCrun.so.1 => /usr/lib/64/libCrun.so.1
libmd.so.1 => /lib/64/libmd.so.1
libxqilla.so.3 => /indisk/TLeft_-32/tibero7/lib/libxqilla.so.3
libxerces-c-3.1.so => /indisk/TLeft_-32/tibero7/lib/libxerces-c-3.1.so
libthread.so.1 => /lib/64/libthread.so.1
libc.so.1 => /lib/64/libc.so.1
libmp.so.2 => /lib/64/libmp.so.2
libucrypto.so.1 => /lib/64/libucrypto.so.1
libelf.so.1 => /lib/64/libelf.so.1
libcryptoutil.so.1 => /lib/64/libcryptoutil.so.1
libz.so.1 => /lib/64/libz.so.1